# HTTPS causes CSS animations to not load? Very confused

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, https

I'm in the final stages of implementing my website, but I'm having a bit of an issue with my JS/CSS animations. On the grammar pages of my Chinese language, there should be yellow highlights over some of my notes on scroll. The problem is, it doesn't do this when I include an https at the beginning of my website url. I don't think this is a code issue, unless there is a snip I will need to include to make it work.

Have a look:

http://www.thechinesewriter.com/story2.html
VS.
https://www.thechinesewriter.com/story2.html

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Some enlightenment would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

mixed content blocked by browser
see:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

and
replace 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
with
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: The same thing will happen with any externally loaded content not served through https. The source of the errors can usually be found by opening the browser's dev tools and reading the output of the console.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you have included some javascript into your page externally, when using https, browser prevents external js to be loaded, if you click on load unsafe scripts in browser url area, u'll see it's working properly. To avoid this situation you must use all the scripts in a script tag in the index.html or site main file.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the "active" class to the highlight with jquery. And your jquery is not being loaded because of the unsecure http link you have included in your script tag.

As your browser console clearly says, your jquery link was blocked because it is of http, instead of https. Major browsers do block unsecure http assets(in this case your jquery link) to be loaded on to a https site.

Instead you can use the https link i.e. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js for both http and https avoiding such an issue.